# How to track conversion in Google Ads for every link click in a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-ads-api

I have a Wordpress page and I need to track all clicks as Google Ads conversion so I've found that I can use the entire page as a link with the following code:

```js
<html>
    <body onclick='window.location.href="http://google.com"'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I need to activate the Google conversion tag at every click and the conversion script are:

```js
<!-- Event snippet for Solicitar cotação conversion page
In your html page, add the snippet and call gtag_report_conversion when someone clicks on the chosen link or button. -->
<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'AW-ID/AWID',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Ok, so please, how can I make every click count as a conversion?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your google snippet should be placed between your `<head></head>` tag. In your child theme or active theme edit your header.php file where you should find the `<head>` tag. I pref to add any snippet before `wp_head()` function. Here is an example of header.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Event snippet for Solicitar cotação conversion page
    In your html page, add the snippet and call gtag_report_conversion when someone clicks on the chosen link or button. -->
    <script>
    function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
    var callback = function () {
        if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
        window.location = url;
        }
    };
    gtag('event', 'conversion', {
        'send_to': 'AW-ID/AWID',
        'event_callback': callback
    });
    return false;
    }
    </script>    
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Read more about how to adapt global site tag for your Google Ads account [here](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7548399?hl=en)

Comment: Hello Martin, thank you for you input. I already have the global tag into the head, that way you said every time the page opens will trigger a conversion but I need to activate it only when a click happen.

Comment: Click on what? Just go create click event. Add this click event to element you want to track eg buttons , links , images. Here is more info about click triggers and other events https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679320?hl=en .